# Rename duplicates in a list of list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am new to python, had a simple question.

I have a list of lists as

```
tempList = [ ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd'] ]
```

I want to rename all subsequent duplicates with  incremental numbers for example:

```
tempList= [ ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a_1', 'd', 'b_1', 'a_2'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'c_1', 'd_1']]
```

I know how to do this for a flat list, but i am not able to find a solution for list of lists. Could anyone give me a pointer on how to do this? The code I tried is as below, does not seem to work.

```
for i in range(0, len(tempList)):
    counts = Counter(tempList[i])
    print(Counter(tempList[i]))
    val = 0
    for s,num in counts.items():
        if num > 1:
            counts[s] = val
            val += 1
        else:
            counts[s] = 0
    tempList = [x if counts[x]==0 else x + str(counts[x]) for x in tempList[i]]
```

Comment: How big are the lists you would be running this on? And if I understand correctly, in a list of lists, you need each list to be treated individually, that is the duplicates within a list needs to be changed but they can repeat between different lists in the same big-list?

Comment: The list would be like about 1000-2000 lists inside the list.
Yes, each list has to be treated individually. every new list of list should be treated separately as in the example i have in my question.

Comment: Do you also need to preserve the order? Example: `[a, b, a, c]` can be converted to `[a, a_1, b, c]` or does it have to be `[a, b, a_1, c]`?

Comment: Yes i need to preserve the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution preserving the order:

```
def foo(l):
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] in d:
            d[l[i]] += 1
            l[i] = l[i] + '_' + str(d[l[i]])
        else:
            d[l[i]] = 0
    return l

list_of_lists = [ ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd'] ]
list_of_lists = [foo(x) for x in list_of_lists]
```

Comment: wow that works, thank you :) i tried this way but i made a mistake on my function inside list comprehension.